# How to flatten Google Analytics custom dimensions with a UDF in BigQuery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Based on [a post by Robert Sahlin](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/google-bigquery-flatten-your-ga-custom-dimensions-udf-robert-sahlin), I want to use a BigQuery UDF to access any Google Analytics custom dimension in BigQuery by its index. In the proposed solution Robert uses a JavaScript UDF, and I'm wondering if it's possible to do the same with a SQL UDF - since a SQL UDF should perform better than a JS one.

The proposed JS UDF:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION customDimensionByIndex(index INT64, arr ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
    if(arr[j].index == index){
      return arr[j].value;
    }
  }
  """;

SELECT 
  fullvisitorId,
  visitId,
  hit.hitnumber,
  customDimensionByIndex(6, hit.customDimensions) as author,
  customDimensionByIndex(7, hit.customDimensions) as category 
FROM `123456.ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD`
JOIN
  UNNEST(hits) as hit﻿
```

Answer (score 7):

With a SQL UDF:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION customDimensionByIndex(indx INT64, arr ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>) AS (
  (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(arr) x WHERE indx=x.index)
);

SELECT 
  fullvisitorId,
  visitId,
  hit.hitnumber,
  customDimensionByIndex(1, hit.customDimensions),
  customDimensionByIndex(2, hit.customDimensions),
  customDimensionByIndex(3, hit.customDimensions)
FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910`, UNNEST(hits) hit
LIMIT 1000
```

*I'm not sure why the original solution looks at "hit" instead of the column "hits" on the sample dataset - so to get to individual hits I had to UNNEST() them too.*

Comment: There is a difference though. The JS UDF does always return a single value (or null). The SQL UDF can return multiple results, which leads to an error: 'Scalar subquery produced more than one element''.

Comment: Related to the previous comment: I actually ran into this on Google Analytics BigQuery data with real data. So it's not just theoretical. I added a `GROUP BY x.value` to get around this for now as it's only a slight offset on my data set.

Comment: If you give me a sample I can test the query on, I can test the query and add fixes.

Comment: to overcome the problem, you can basically add an aggregation function before select'ing `x.value`, like `select max(x.value)`, for example